# How can I attach a tripod to my backpack (Lowepro fastpack 350)?

Tags: tripod, camera-bag

I bought a Ravelli 65" tripod 
The tripod comes with a carry bag but it doesn't feel too comfortable 
So I have been doing some research in regards to the alternatives to attach the tripod to my backpack which is Lowepro fastpack 350.
And I found the below given youtube video

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bJbcyM9stSI

I was wondering whether there is a better alternative than this ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

When your backpack has compression straps on the side — as [these](http://www.treloarphysio.com/img/backpack%20compr%20straps.jpg) [have](http://www.modernbushman.com/2012/04/03/voodoo-tactical-field-medical-backpack/) —, I find these not just immensely useful in keeping the gear in shape, it also holds a tripod very well in an upright position. Which is in my experience a lot nicer when moving in cities, especially public transport. Just slide it between straps and the back pack, then pull tight.

I am aware this does not quite help with the Fastpak 350 (at least not unmodified), but is given in the hope of helping others with tripod mounting needs. But nonetheless, grabbing some straps from sleep sacks / foam insulation mats and repurposing them for this might be useful. :)

Answer (score 0):

I have a backpack from Kata, where the tripod is attached vertically to the rear of the backpack:
It looks similar as this:

http://www.ephotocraft.com/itemdesc.asp?ic=719821297772

or this

http://i3.sdlcdn.com/img/product/main/Kata_KT_DL_3N1_33_3in1_Sling_Backpackm_5_2x.jpg

It kind of works. Don't know if you can pimp your Lowe backpack to do this.